# How to read syslog messages as a normal user?

Tags: linux, posix, syslog

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04**. By default `/var/log/syslog` is readable only by `adm` group members.

```
$ls -lh /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 23M Oct 29 10:20 /var/log/syslog
```

I tried using `dmesg -f syslog`, but it is also not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You cannot, as you say they are only accessible by `adm` group members.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the output directory in the syslog.conf, but I don't think you can change the group:owner.  If you install syslog-ng, you can set the global options to output files with whatever rights you require.

```
create_dirs(yes);
dir_group("root");
dir_owner("adm");
dir_perm(0755);
```